# Convert from base 10 to any base in between 2 and 36 Go

Tags: javascript, string, go

how can one convert from base 10 to any base  2-36 in go?

in javascript you just

```
Number.toString(radix?)
```

e.g.

var number = 12345;
console.log(my_number.toString(36).toUpperCase());

in go this is how you can achieve the same effect

```
func convertToAnyBase2to36(num int64, base int64) string {
    var len int64 = base
    var source_string = []string{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "J", "I", "J", "K",
    "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X","Y","Z"}
    code := "";
    for {
        if num <= 0 {
            break
        }
        mod := num % len;
        num = (num - mod) / len;
        code =  source_string[mod]+code;
    }
    return code
}
```

e.g

```
fmt.Println(convertToAnyBase2to36(12354,2))
```

Comment: Are you attempting to answer your own question? If so, you should put the answer in the Answer box. (or are you having a problem with the code? - in which case you should describe the problems you're having with it)

Answer (score 4):

In Go you have [`strconv.FormatInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt) (and [`strconv.FormatUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint)):

```
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(12345, 2))
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(12345, 16))
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(12345, 32))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N4F44DAiB77)):

```
11000000111001
3039
c1p
```